# Deploying Java EE app in JBoss AS: Can not find a free port for use

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, port, jboss5.x

I have a big problem deploying a Java EE project on a JBoss AS 5.1GA (a little bit out of date but my university suggest this one).

I noticed that the problem is

```
ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: 
name=jboss.messaging:service=Connector,transport=bisocket state=Create mode=Manual 
requiredState=Installed
    java.io.IOException: Can not find a free port for use.
```

but I've put the entire console output below.

The same projects with same `JBoss` config and so on works fine on my friends machine.. So, I think this is a problem only on my PC but I don't think that it's some firewall issue because I've already tried to shut down all of them...

Below (maybe) helpful info

SO: `Windows 8 64bit`

```
23:28:59,956 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
23:28:59,957 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [The Oracle] 5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)
23:28:59,957 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null
23:28:59,957 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA
23:28:59,958 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/
23:28:59,958 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/
23:28:59,959 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null
23:28:59,959 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/
23:28:59,959 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/lib/
23:28:59,959 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: default
23:28:59,959 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server
23:28:59,959 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/
23:28:59,960 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/
23:28:59,960 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default
23:28:59,960 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/
23:28:59,960 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\data
23:28:59,960 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/lib/
23:28:59,960 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\log
23:28:59,960 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp\native
23:28:59,960 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp
23:28:59,961 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp\deploy
23:29:00,908 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
23:29:01,629 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Initializing VFSCache [org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.CombinedVFSCache]
23:29:01,632 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Using VFSCache [CombinedVFSCache[real-cache: null]]
23:29:01,924 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: C:\Software Development\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp
23:29:01,934 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is enabled.
23:29:03,322 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.7.0_09,Oracle Corporation
23:29:03,323 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
23:29:03,323 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.5-b02,Oracle Corporation
23:29:03,323 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 8 6.2,amd64
23:29:03,324 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
23:29:03,358 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
23:29:05,773 INFO  [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Loading profile: ProfileKey@54985ce4[domain=default, server=default, name=default]
23:29:07,733 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
23:29:15,847 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core
23:29:15,848 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] 3.1.2.GA
23:29:16,493 INFO  [AttributeCallbackItem] Owner callback not implemented.
23:29:18,249 INFO  [LogNotificationListener] Adding notification listener for logging mbean "jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl@641c8053[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]
23:29:30,331 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@1427365531{vfszip:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/Swimv2.jar/}
23:29:30,332 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@1427365531{vfszip:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/Swimv2.jar/}
23:29:30,336 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@559468067{vfsfile:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
23:29:30,336 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@559468067{vfsfile:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
23:29:30,337 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@559468067{vfsfile:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
23:29:30,337 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@559468067{vfsfile:/C:/Software%20Development/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
23:29:33,330 INFO  [JMXConnectorServerService] JMX Connector server: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/jmxconnector
23:29:33,605 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
23:29:33,981 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.messaging:service=Connector,transport=bisocket state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
java.io.IOException: Can not find a free port for use.
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.PortUtil.findFreePort(PortUtil.java:145)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker.start(BisocketServerInvoker.java:224)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.Connector.start(Connector.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at [ .... ]
```

As suggested
I've checked the file mentioned and found the part

```
<attribute name="serverBindPort">${jboss.messaging.connector.bisocket.port:4457    }</attribute>
```

But when i look for this port on SysinternalsTCPView, I found no matching with port 4457.
There's what TCPView showed up.

```
svchost.exe 232 TCP vitokr-pc   epmap   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 232 TCPV6   vitokr-pc   epmap   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   UDP vitokr-pc   netbios-ns  *   *       147 7.350   9   450                     
System  4   UDP vitokr-pc   netbios-dgm *   *       3   621 3   621                     
System  4   TCP vitokr-pc   netbios-ssn vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCP vitokr-pc   microsoft-ds    vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCPV6   vitokr-pc   microsoft-ds    vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 1040    UDP vitokr-pc   isakmp  *   *                                           
svchost.exe 1040    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   500 *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *               532 166.547                     
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *               460 138.239                     
svchost.exe 2400    UDP vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDPV6   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]   ssdp    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   ssdp    *   *                                           
System  4   TCP vitokr-pc   icslap  vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCPV6   vitokr-pc   icslap  vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
mysqld-nt.exe   3716    TCP vitokr-pc   3306    vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
dasHost.exe 1244    UDP vitokr-pc   ws-discovery    *   *                                           
dasHost.exe 1244    UDP vitokr-pc   ws-discovery    *   *                                           
dasHost.exe 1244    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   3702    *   *                                           
dasHost.exe 1244    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   3702    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 1072    UDP vitokr-pc   ws-discovery    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDP vitokr-pc   ws-discovery    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDP vitokr-pc   ws-discovery    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 1072    UDP vitokr-pc   ws-discovery    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   3702    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 1072    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   3702    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   3702    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 1072    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   3702    *   *                                           
svchost.exe 1040    UDP vitokr-pc   ipsec-msft  *   *                                           
svchost.exe 1040    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   4500    *   *                                           
mDNSResponder.exe   1888    UDP vitokr-pc   5353    *   *       1   42  23  3.110                       
mDNSResponder.exe   1888    UDPV6   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]   5353    *   *                                           
mDNSResponder.exe   1888    TCP vitokr-pc   5354    vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
mDNSResponder.exe   1888    TCP vitokr-pc   5354    localhost   49155   ESTABLISHED                                     
svchost.exe 1256    UDP vitokr-pc   llmnr   *   *               269 6.692                       
svchost.exe 1256    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   5355    *   *                                           
System  4   TCP vitokr-pc   wsd vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCPV6   vitokr-pc   wsd vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
postgres.exe    2668    TCP vitokr-pc   5432    vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
postgres.exe    2668    TCPV6   vitokr-pc   5432    vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
TeamViewer_Service.exe  2632    TCP vitokr-pc   5939    vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
TeamViewer_Service.exe  2632    TCP vitokr-pc   5939    localhost   56659   ESTABLISHED         12  516                     
System  4   TCP vitokr-pc   12372   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCPV6   vitokr-pc   12372   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCPV6   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]   12372   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]   56669   ESTABLISHED 275 52.189  278 45.870                      
Dropbox.exe 5604    TCP vitokr-pc   17500   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING   104 20.696  104 20.696                      
Dropbox.exe 5604    UDP vitokr-pc   17500   *   *                                           
Dropbox.exe 5604    TCP vitokr-pc   19872   localhost   56691   ESTABLISHED                                     
AppleMobileDeviceService.exe    1608    TCP vitokr-pc   27015   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
AppleMobileDeviceService.exe    1608    TCP vitokr-pc   27015   localhost   56664   ESTABLISHED                                     
wininit.exe 772 TCP vitokr-pc   49152   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
wininit.exe 772 TCPV6   vitokr-pc   49152   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 924 TCP vitokr-pc   49153   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 924 TCPV6   vitokr-pc   49153   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 1040    TCP vitokr-pc   49154   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 1040    TCPV6   vitokr-pc   49154   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
AppleMobileDeviceService.exe    1608    TCP vitokr-pc   49155   localhost   5354    ESTABLISHED                                     
lsass.exe   884 TCP vitokr-pc   49156   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
lsass.exe   884 TCPV6   vitokr-pc   49156   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 1072    UDP vitokr-pc   49161   *   *                                           
svchost.exe 1072    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   49162   *   *                                           
services.exe    868 TCP vitokr-pc   49164   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
services.exe    868 TCPV6   vitokr-pc   49164   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 2256    TCP vitokr-pc   49165   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 2256    TCPV6   vitokr-pc   49165   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    TCP vitokr-pc   50041   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   50041   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP 169.254.204.244 50612   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP 10.169.195.211  51090   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP 192.168.0.100   51108   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   52042   *   *       72  28.308                              
svchost.exe 2400    UDP vitokr-pc   52314   *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   52315   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    TCP vitokr-pc   53168   vitokr-pc   0   LISTENING                                       
svchost.exe 2400    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   54294   *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDPV6   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]   54295   *   *                                           
svchost.exe 2400    UDP vitokr-pc   54296   *   *       30  3.990   270 84.180                      
svchost.exe 2400    UDP vitokr-pc   54297   *   *       30  3.990                               
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   55097   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP 192.168.0.100   55861   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP 169.254.204.244 56595   *   *                                           
TeamViewer.exe  6468    TCP vitokr-pc   56657   localhost   56658   ESTABLISHED                                     
TeamViewer.exe  6468    TCP vitokr-pc   56658   localhost   56657   ESTABLISHED                                     
TeamViewer.exe  6468    TCP vitokr-pc   56659   localhost   5939    ESTABLISHED 12  516                             
iTunesHelper.exe    4628    TCP vitokr-pc   56664   localhost   27015   ESTABLISHED                                     
Connectify.exe  4732    TCPV6   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]   56669   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]   12372   ESTABLISHED 278 45.870  275 52.189                      
Dropbox.exe 5604    TCP vitokr-pc   56691   localhost   19872   ESTABLISHED                                     
TeamViewer_Service.exe  2632    TCP vitokr-pc   56733   server1101.teamviewer.com   https   ESTABLISHED 13  312 13  312                     
explorer.exe    5900    TCP vitokr-pc   56741   157.55.236.106  https   ESTABLISHED                                     
Dropbox.exe 5604    TCP vitokr-pc   56778   v-d-2a.sjc.dropbox.com  https   CLOSE_WAIT                                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56833   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.198   2   445                     
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56834   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 7   4.093   33  39.562                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56835   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.248   2   448                     
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56836   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 5   3.105   5   1.116                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56837   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.132   7   10.770                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56838   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.201   2   444                     
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56845   208.81.234.118  http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.449   26  56.245                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56866   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 37  30.018  37  9.059                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56867   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 78  61.842  78  19.114                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56868   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 9   7.128   9   2.212                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56889   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 4   2.622   6   3.000                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56922   62.208.24.27    http    ESTABLISHED 4   3.537   72  171.832                     
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56951   81.88.48.90 http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.870   4   2.014                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56958   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.253   4   2.055                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56959   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 5   3.020   15  21.577                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56960   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 3   1.838   7   11.150                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56961   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 3   1.788   15  48.892                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56976   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 4   2.052   4   888                     
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56979   fa-in-f125.1e100.net    https   ESTABLISHED         2   74                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56991   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.235   5   3.872                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56992   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.236   5   3.407                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56993   95.101.34.34    http    ESTABLISHED 2   1.254   6   3.114                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56994   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 3   1.817   14  45.118                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56995   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 6   3.605   20  17.270                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   56996   95.101.34.40    http    ESTABLISHED 4   2.402   14  17.211                      
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   57102   *   *                                           
Dropbox.exe 5604    TCP vitokr-pc   57275   sjc-not15.sjc.dropbox.com   http    ESTABLISHED 11  4.169   22  1.969                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   57338   62.208.24.82    https   ESTABLISHED 1   709 1   389                     
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   57339   62.208.24.82    https   ESTABLISHED 1   741 5   8.805                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   57340   62.208.24.82    https   ESTABLISHED 1   693 1   389                     
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   57352   2.18.31.144 http    ESTABLISHED 1   1.264   2   405                     
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   57354   2.18.31.144 http    ESTABLISHED 1   1.087   3   1.408                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   57355   mil01s17-in-f2.1e100.net    https   ESTABLISHED 26  61.360  56  55.635                      
explorer.exe    5900    TCP vitokr-pc   57452   a213-254-17-64.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com    http    CLOSE_WAIT                                      
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   57461   gru03s16-in-f15.1e100.net   https   ESTABLISHED 5   1.423   7   2.428                       
chrome.exe  6480    TCP vitokr-pc   57511   muc03s08-in-f18.1e100.net   https   ESTABLISHED                                     
[System Process]    0   TCP vitokr-pc   57516   r-199-59-148-20.twttr.com   http    TIME_WAIT                                       
AppleMobileDeviceService.exe    1608    UDP vitokr-pc   58245   *   *                                           
AppleMobileDeviceService.exe    1608    UDP vitokr-pc   58246   *   *                                           
mDNSResponder.exe   1888    UDP vitokr-pc   58247   *   *                                           
mDNSResponder.exe   1888    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   58248   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP 192.168.0.100   58338   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP 10.169.195.211  58500   *   *                                           
Skype.exe   4308    UDP vitokr-pc   58909   *   *       1   1   1   1                       
iTunesHelper.exe    4628    UDP vitokr-pc   58910   *   *                                           
iTunesHelper.exe    4628    UDP vitokr-pc   58911   *   *                                           
dasHost.exe 1244    UDP vitokr-pc   59036   *   *                                           
dasHost.exe 1244    UDPV6   vitokr-pc   59037   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP vitokr-pc   59199   *   *                                           
MezzmoMediaServer.exe   2132    UDP 192.168.0.100   61198   *   *                                           
postgres.exe    2668    UDPV6   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]   63157   *   *       14  320 14  320
```

Comment: Open `http://localhost:8080` in your browser. What do you see?

Comment: @BalusC I see the main page of JBoss, where i can monitor the server and so on.

Comment: Then it's already started from outside the IDE's control on. You need to shutdown it before being able to start it from inside the IDE.

Comment: I don't think so because, also with the error the server runs but doesn't deploy all the project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name=jboss.messaging:service=Connector,transport=bisocket`'s port is defined in `deploy\messaging\remoting-bisocket-service.xml` as

```
<attribute name="serverBindPort">${jboss.messaging.connector.bisocket.port:4457}</attribute>
```

You can use [SysInternals TCPView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows/) to find what other application is holding this port and even release it.

**UPDATE**

The problem appears to be a known issue described here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/160779.

Comment: Thanks, but i've tried without success.. I have edited the main post with other details.

Comment: `port:4457    }` these extra spaces could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: maybe I made a mistake doing copy and paste but there is no such spaces in the original page..

Comment: Could you try to start JBoss with `-b REAL.IP` instead of localhost or  0.0.0.0? Also try disabling firewall.

Comment: Also take a look at https://community.jboss.org/thread/160779 and https://community.jboss.org/thread/160000

Comment: I followed the instructions on the second link adding a secondaryBindPort (tried 4458).. Now I don't have the problem anymore but I've another type of exception and I think is not related to the previous. Thanks for help